# Propogated Measurement Uncertainty in Dimensionless Result

Tags: measurement-error, measurement, spectral-analysis

When collecting measurements which each have a certain amount of associated uncertainty, and subsequently using them to create a dimensionless result (like a ratio), how exactly is the uncertainty applied to the final dimensionless result?

I've been collecting measurements with a spectrometer, each of which has a certain amount of uncertainty. The measurements are collected as absolute values in the form of Digital Numbers (DNs). Through analysis of multiple measurements of an identical target, I've determined that the measurement uncertainty is normally distributed via a normal probability plot and I've determined the absolute measurement uncertainty of each measurement at a 95% confidence interval.

Measurements of separate targets (white reference, and target spectra) are used to create a dimensionless result in the form of the percent of reflectance from a given target in relation to the white reference value. For example, a white reference of 50,000 +- 500 DNs and a target value of 20,000 DNs +- 500 DNs would lead to a result of: (20,000 / 50,000) = 40% reflectance +- 3.5% percent uncertainty (percent uncertainty being used because the measurements were divided by one another).

Normally, the 3.5% uncertainty would then be converted back into the units of measurement with which it was collected. How is this +-3.5% uncertainty appplied to the dimensionless reflectance value? Is it as simple as multiplying (40% * 0.035) = 1.4%, leading to a final measurement with associated uncertainty of 40% +- 1.4%? Or would it be applied to the dimensionless result some other way?